# rt_raster_gdal_warp error while importing raster data into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster

I am trying to import raster data into PostGIS. Documentation tells me to run `raster2pgsql`, which I do with the following command:

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -M -F -s 910001 test.tif mytable | psql -d postgis_test -U postgres
```

Here, SRID 910001 is self-defined to match the data that I have (check below). Now, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
FEHLER:  rt_raster_gdal_warp: Could not create GDAL transformation object for output dataset creation
KONTEXT:  SQL-Funktion Â»st_transformÂ« Anweisung 1
```

(FEHLER means ERROR and KONTEXT means CONTEXT). Googling the issue leads to http://126kr.com/article/5byaz3d0uvp, which suggests checking if PROJ is defined and PROJSO set correctly. So I have set `PROJSO="libproj-9.dll"` and `SELECT postgis_full_version()` yields

```
POSTGIS="2.3.1 r15264" GEOS="3.6.0-CAPI-1.10.0 r4265" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.1, released 2016/07/07" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" RASTER
```

I suppose that is fine. I have defined the projection as follows with WKT string

```
PROJCS["WRF experiment 1",GEOGCS["WRF Sphere",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["WRF  Sphere",6370000,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",47.83],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",11.01],
PARAMETER["false_easting",36.5],
PARAMETER["false_northing",-30],
UNIT["unknown",15000]]
```

and PROJ string

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=30 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=47.83 +lon_0=11.01 +x_0=547500 +y_0=-450000 +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +to_meter=15000
```

(I generated the WKT string from the PROJ one using gdalsrsinfo). Visual inspection with QGIS shows that the PROJ string works. 
I am on Windows using Postgis 9.6. I have no idea on how to further debug this. Is there a way to get more verbose output? I can provide my data if it helps.

Comment: Custom SRIDs have a valid range of 910000 to 998999. Please **edit** your question so the title focuses on the actual problem.

Comment: @Vince, I have changed the SRID in the question and my database, the issue remains though. I was unsure about the title. Maybe this one is a bit better but I fail at giving a very good one.